# c# How do I return the error code and the error text to the calling application?

Tags: c#

I know how to return the error code in c#, I am not sure if there is a special way of setting up the return error text that you can get as well?

This is for a console application.

```
{
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("args is null"); // Check for null array
        }

        Console.Write("args length is ");
        Console.WriteLine(args.Length); // Write array length ( Number of items )

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
        {
            string argument = args[i];
            Console.Write("args index ");
            Console.Write(i); // Write index
            Console.Write(" is [");
            Console.Write(argument); // Write string
            Console.WriteLine("]");
        }

        return 0; // error code exit

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any code you could show us as to what you've tried/what you're expecting?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about setting up the error text. The only thing I currently know how to do is: return 0; , or whatever the exit code is I want to return.

Comment: My question remains - is this a console application, forms application... what?  It'd help if you show some code so we can determine what you're after.

Comment: Added sample code and comments. I don;t have any 'real' code as I am just starting and testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap it in a try catch block, and it will bubble up to the calling application.

If you need to do cleanup before you exit your code, then

```
   Try
   {


   }
   Catch(Exception e)
   {
      throw;

   }
```

That will throw the error to the calling application, and the calling application can decide what to do about it.

You also want to document which exceptions might be thrown by your methods so that the calling application knows what exceptions to be prepared to deal with.

Comment: No, this will throw in the WER service to clean up your application's mess.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes it will, but in the case of an exception that needs to be reported back to the calling application with the Exception information intact, that would seem appropriate.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, throwing the exception will return both the error code, and the associated text?

Comment: It will. It will return the entire exception object.

Comment: When you do `throw e;`, the original stacktrace is lost; use `throw;` instead.  And this won't compile because the capitalization is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`Environment.ExitCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode(v=vs.110).aspx). `0` means 'OK'. Any other value is considered bad.

```
Environment.ExitCode = -1; /* something went wrong!!! */
```

There is no property for the error text, but you could supply what with the standard output.

Full example:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = -1;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);

    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: This does not give the calling application the exception information. It only tells the calling application that an exception occured.

Comment: That is the intention of the `ErrorCode` field, yes.

Comment: The OP needs the error code, and Exception Text passed back to the calling application.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but setting the Exit Code to something other than 0 doesn't pass the Exception that occurred to the calling application.

Comment: That is the purpose of the `Console.Out`.

Comment: @ChuckBuford: Updated the answer for clarification.

Comment: @SuperSteve: Need more help?